# Using PHP to extract information from attributes in XML document

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, xml-attribute

I was unable to find an answer to my question after browsing some promising titles so I figured I would try my luck!

I'm attempting to extract information from XML files generated from a back-end we use at work. The information is not formatted like a normal XML document, so it's been a little difficult to extract what I need. I'm hoping that I can eventually put this information in a table, but I'll be happy if I can at least extract the values.

An example string is as follows:

```
<Event Name="Last Reef" VenueName="Theater" EventDate="2014-03-21 15:00:00" DirectLink="https://tickets.ctsciencecenter.org/Public/loader.asp?target=hall.asp?event=45259"/>
```

And I'm trying to get:

```
Event Name:
Venue Name:
Event Date:
Direct Link:
```

I'm assuming I need to use substr, but I've never dealt with a string like this.

If you take a moment to look at this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: The formatting is correct for an XML document (assuming that this is just a fragment of a document). You need to be looking at how to find the values of attributes (Name, VenueName, EventDate, DirectLink are attributes of the Event element). Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php for hints.

Comment: What gave you the impression that it was poorly formatted? Was it because it made use of attributes rather than nested elements?

Comment: @w5m - To tell you the truth, I'm not very familiar with XML documents, when I read some examples online, they didn't seem to use attributes as heavily. After reading the links provided, I now understand how attributes work in XML documents and that it IS correct formatting. Thank you.

Comment: No problem - I was just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`simplexml_load_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) makes working with XML easy for basic tasks like this:

```
<?php
$event= simplexml_load_string('<Event Name="Last Reef" VenueName="Theater" EventDate="2014-03-21 15:00:00" DirectLink="https://tickets.ctsciencecenter.org/Public/loader.asp?target=hall.asp?event=45259"/>');
?>

Event Name: <?= $event['Name']; ?><br>
Venue Name: <?= $event['VenueName']; ?><br>
Event Date: <?= $event['EventDate']; ?><br>
Direct Link: <?= $event['DirectLink']; ?>
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4rvW1G)

Comment: Thank you as well! This works great. In the XML document, there are about 20 instances of that string, it currently shows the first one, how would I make it display for each <Event> string?

Comment: It would be worth you looking at XPath if you need more power in your data manipulations.

Comment: Thank you @w5m, I'm look at the documentation for it now.

Comment: For example: print_r($event->xpath("//Event")); does a global search for all "Event" elements and returns the corresponding array. See: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/12/3/3

Comment: @w5m - This page is very helpful! Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Or try a regex:

```
$str = '<Event Name="Last Reef" VenueName="Theater" EventDate="2014-03-21 15:00:00" DirectLink="https://tickets.ctsciencecenter.org/Public/loader.asp?target=hall.asp?event=45259"/>';

preg_match('/Name="([^"]*)".+VenueName="([^"]*)".+EventDate="([^"]*)".+DirectLink="([^"]*)"/',$str,$output);

echo '<pre>';

print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Name="Last Reef" VenueName="Theater" EventDate="2014-03-21 15:00:00" DirectLink="https://tickets.ctsciencecenter.org/Public/loader.asp?target=hall.asp?event=45259"
    [1] => Last Reef
    [2] => Theater
    [3] => 2014-03-21 15:00:00
    [4] => https://tickets.ctsciencecenter.org/Public/loader.asp?target=hall.asp?event=45259
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple example I've come up with which uses XPath to return all matching `Event` elements and outputs the data as an HTML table ([view output here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JQ5yfV)) and uses the attribute names as column headings. I added in an extra `Event` element to demonstrate iterating over multiple elements (and wrapped the `Event` elements within an `Events` element as valid XML documents must have a single root element).

```
<?php

function FormatData($data, $linkText = 'Link') {
  if (substr($data, 0, 4) === 'http') {
    if ($linkText === '') $linkText = $data;
    return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $data, $linkText);        
  } else {
    return $data;
  }
}    

$xmlData = simplexml_load_string('<Events><Event Name="Last Reef" VenueName="Theater" EventDate="2014-03-21 15:00:00" DirectLink="https://tickets.ctsciencecenter.org/Public/loader.asp?target=hall.asp?event=45259"/><Event Name="Hidden Universe" VenueName="Theater" EventDate="2014-03-22 13:00:00" DirectLink="https://tickets.ctsciencecenter.org/Public/loader.asp?target=hall.asp?event=45695"/></Events>');

// do a global search to retrieve all "Event" elements
$events = $xmlData->xpath('//Event');

if (count($events) > 0) {

  // get attribute names of first "Event" element
  foreach($events[0]->attributes() as $attribute) {
    $attributeNames[] = $attribute->getName(); 
  }
  // output as table column headings
  echo '<table border="1"><tr><th>' . implode('</th><th>', $attributeNames) . '</th></tr>';

  // iterate through each "Event" element and access each attribute value
  foreach($events as $event) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($attributeNames as $attributeName) {
      echo '<td>' . FormatData($event[$attributeName]) . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';   
  } 
  echo '</table>';

} else {
  echo 'No matching elements found';
}

?>
```

Comment: Hey this is great - thank you very much @w5m! I really appreciate your help and I've learned a good amount about XML / Xpath from asking my original question!

Comment: So I guess now my only concern now is that the last column of links do not auto-link. I was just looking at this [link](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js), and I was wondering how to target (I assume the best way is jQuery) the content in those columns.

Comment: Actually, I think I've solved this issue, here is an example: [link](http://dev.ctsciencecenter.org/xmlpeo/)

Comment: Unfortunately, the 2nd link you provided was blocked so I can't see how you implemented it. The 1st link (Autolinker.js) looks very useful and comprehensive. If your needs were very basic you could create a simple function that assumes any attribute value beginning with "http" should be formatted as a hyperlink - see my edited post.

Comment: Are you using a phone? I have mobile devices blocked for that site. Your implementation works great - I wish I was more familiar with selecting specific content with PHP, I'm going to try your method because it doesn't require jQuery.

Comment: No, I'm using Chrome on a laptop. A few useful functions for string manipulation that are worth knowing are: substr (return a portion of a string), strpos (find position of text within a string) and str_replace (replace occurrences of text within a string). For a full list see: http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php and if you want real power, try Regular Expressions!

Answer (score 0):

I think, SimpleXml can do this. Just add Some like this:

```
 $xml_string = '<Event Name="Last Reef" VenueName="Theater" EventDate="2014-03-21 15:00:00" DirectLink="https://tickets.ctsciencecenter.org/Public/loader.asp?target=hall.asp?event=45259"/>';  
 $xml        = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0"?> '.$xml_string);
 $attributes =$xml->attributes();
 echo 'Event Name:'.$attributes['Name'];
 echo 'Venue Name:'.$attributes['VenueName'];
 echo 'Event Date:'.$attributes['EventDate'];
 echo 'Direct Link:'.$attributes['DirectLink'];
```